# Find the correct figure

Tags: sequence

I am seriously stuck here. According to my opinion: the columns do not provide any information. So the rows need to be checked. The semi circles seem either to combine or cancel arrows. I am clueless.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the answer is

> The third tile (Blank)

This is because

> Every row has exactly one left arc, one right arc, one left arrow, one right arrow, and one double-sided arrow. The third row already has all of those things, so the last tile doesn't need any symbols on it.